# Post publish only hook?

Tags: posts, publish

Is there any hook which is fired only when the post is "published" for the first time.

I dont want to execute my code when the post is "updated" or when its status is set to "not-published" and then "published" again.

EDIT:

```
add_action('draft_to_published','func_tion');

function func_tion($post){
    $post_id = $post->ID;   

    if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mycoderan', $single = true ) )
    // run code to manipulate data
    wp_enqueue_script('plugin_name',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ).'script.js');
    $params = array() // set parameters
    wp_localize_script('plugin_name', 'params', $params );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mycoderan', true );
}
```

Comment: You have to enclose everything in the `if` statement inside `{ ... }` braces. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Comment: I need similar functionality, but can't figure out how to check if a post is being published for the first time or not. `draft_to_published ` action seem to be triggered every time a post is published from draft multiple times. Are you relying on post meta to check if a post is published for the 1st time.  Is there any native WP function that can be used instead?

Comment: @dashaluna Please review the answer to my other question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46783/in-what-sequence-are-the-hooks-fired-when-a-post-is-published?rq=1 With Wordpress 3.5, there have been a few changes so what you've written is also possible. The flow script should be tremendous help in this. Helped me alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B%24old_status%7D_to_%7B%24new_status%7D) and [`{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B%24new_status%7D_%7B%24post-%3Epost_type%7D) hooks tend to generally solve the problem.

To avoid running the code in case post status is changed to draft then published again (after already being published), implement a simple flag using the `post_meta` functionality.

**Note**: the updated hook should be 'draft_to_publish' instead of 'draft_to_published' however, the code below is not modified and should be if you plan to use in WP 3.5

```
add_action( 'draft_to_published', 'wpse47566_do_once_on_publish' );
function wpse47566_do_once_on_publish( $post ) {
    // check post type if necessary
    if ( $post->post_type != 'a_specific_type' ) return;

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mycoderan', $single = true ) ) {
        // ...run code once
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mycoderan', true );
    }
}
```

Comment: my code should run on any category type so i dont think i need this line
`// check post type if necessary
    if ( $post->post_type != 'a_specific_type' ) return;
`
i have written my query within this function to get the post data and then i have to run a script by passing the post data as parameters... your function requires the post as an argument... so is the following ok??

Comment: `add_action( 'draft_to_published', 'func_tion' );
function func_tion() {
    /* query code */
    if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mycoderan', $single = true ) )
        // ...run code once
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mycoderan', true );
}


`

Comment: the `{$status}_to_{$status}` action passes on the `$post` object, so `$post_id = $post->ID`, fixed my answer.

Comment: i'm sorry i didnt know comments cannot process new-lines... i have only written the query to get post data inside the function... then i enqueue and localize the script inside the `// run code once ` block... is that ok??

Comment: i have edited the question... please let me know why my script is not executing.. where am i going wrong??

Comment: if i add a function with the following three lines to init hook, the script executes just fine...
    `wp_enqueue_script('plugin_name',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ).'script.js');`
    `$params = array() // set parameters`
    `wp_localize_script('plugin_name', 'params', $params );`

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you sure the hook is pulled? http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions could it be pending. Also you did not encapsulate the `if` statement code inside `{ ... }`?

Comment: So sorry for such a late response. Better late than never! The accepted solution worked like a charm