# Emailing Authors only when a CUSTOM POST TYPE post is published- not when edited later

Tags: custom-post-types, author, email, publish

I have the following function that emails authors of a **custom post type** when the post is published which is great, but I would like it so that it does not email them on any future edits after that to avoid sending them loads of emails by accident.

This is the function I have at the moment:

```
//email authors
function authorNotification($post_id) {
   $post = get_post($post_id);
   $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);

   $message = "Hi ".$author->display_name.".
A document for you, ".$post->post_title." has just been published or edited and requires your attention. 
You will be taken to the document after you log in from this link: ".get_permalink( $post_id ).".
   ";
   wp_mail($author->user_email, "An online document has been made or edited for you.", $message);
}
add_action('publish_portaldocuments', 'authorNotification');
```

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the The {$old_status}*to*{$new_status} and {$new_status}_{$post->post_type} hooks as on this page: [Post publish only hook?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47566/post-publish-only-hook)

Could someone help please as I'm not sure how I would implement it WITH A CUSTOM POST TYPE.
Thanks :-)

**Update**: This worked for me:

```
// SEND EMAIL TO AUTHOR OF A CUSTOM POST TYPE ONCE POST IS PUBLISHED

function authorNotification($post_id) {
    if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) ) {
 $post = get_post($post_id);
   $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);

   $message = "Hi ".$author->display_name.".
A document for you, ".$post->post_title." has just been published or edited and requires your attention. 
You will be taken to the document after you log in from this link: ".get_permalink( $post_id ).".
   ";
   wp_mail($author->user_email, "An online document has been made or edited for you.", $message);
    }
}

add_action( 'publish_portaldocuments', 'authorNotification' );
```

Comment: I have updated the linked answer with a post type restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like you do want a [post transition hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions), probably `draft_to_publish` as per the following from the Codex:

```
function your_callback( $post ) {
    // Code here
}
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'your_callback' );
```

Use `authorNotification`-- your function name-- instead of `your_callback`. It should be fairly simple in your case.

However, the precise details of your project are not clear. You may require something more complex. I can't tell.

Comment: An alternative to the `draft_to_publish` hook would be if you wanted to make this a one hit without relying on the status changes. In some editorial workflows the status of the content may change over time, as such the notifications might be falsely triggered. Adding an additional lookup to a custom meta field within the `draft_to_publish` hook (as mentioned by s_ha_dum) it would allow the ability to resend later if you really need too but not limit to only status changes.

Comment: I appreciate your help.Basically instead of getting emails every time the post is updated, I just want to send the message if it is first published. I can't make this 'draft_to_publish' work with my custom post type 'portaldocuments'.

Comment: Edit your question to include the altered code-- the code using the post status hook. And check the post marked as a duplicate by toscho.

Comment: I found the answer thanks. I appreciate you guys pointing me in the right direction, this was useful as well: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post. How do I post my solution? Do I just edit the question? Sorry about the duplicate but I was a bit stuck.

Comment: If you have a solution you wish to post you can, and should, post an answer in the "Answer" box just like any other user.

Comment: I think because it's my own question I can't see or have access to the answer box like on other questions by other people. I put the code I used in my original question. Sorry about that. Thanks again for your help though.